# Error : save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and i'm trying to install custom module named odoo_qr_code  which allow to add qr code in products form and create qr image for products and products variants. But when i press save after adding my qr code in product forms it shows error. Any help please ?

```
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0rc20180515\openerp\addons\odoo_qr_code\models\models.py", line 23, in _generate_qr_code
img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'
```

models.py

```
import base64
import cStringIO

import qrcode
from openerp import models, fields, api


class ProductTemplateQRCode(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
@api.depends('product_qr_code')
def _generate_qr_code(self):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L, box_size=20, border=4)
    if self.product_qr_code:
        name = self.product_qr_code + '_product.png'
        qr.add_data(self.product_qr_code)
        qr.make(fit=True)
        img = qr.make_image()
        buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
        img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
        qrcode_img = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
        self.update({'qr_code': qrcode_img, 'qr_code_name': name})

product_qr_code = fields.Char('QR Code')
qr_code = fields.Binary('QR Code', compute="_generate_qr_code")
qr_code_name = fields.Char(default="qr_code.png")


class ProductProductQRCode(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.product'

@api.multi
@api.depends('product_qr_code')
def _generate_qr_code(self):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L, box_size=20, border=4)
    if self.product_qr_code:
        name = self.product_qr_code + '_product.png'
        qr.add_data(self.product_qr_code)
        qr.make(fit=True)
        img = qr.make_image()
        buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
        img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
        qrcode_img = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
        self.update({'qr_code': qrcode_img, 'qr_code_name': name})
```

Comment: If this is a custom module that you have no control over, you should find the owner of that code, and file a bug for them to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The error states that the function `save` is not accepting argument `format`. So you need to remove it (from both functions).

You can refer this [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/554/how-to-create-a-qr-code-image-or-svg-in-python) link for `how to create QR code in python`.

Hope it will help you.